# Getting started with Angular and Mobile Angular UI

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I am 100% new to angular/mobile angular ui.  I just finished installing visual studio code and am attempting to create a mobile editable grid.  I am following the getting started guide:

http://mobileangularui.com/docs/getting-started/

And have completed the command:

```
npm install --save mobile-angular-ui angular angular-route
```

Now it shows some code right under the above command (in the same link above):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>My App</title>
<!-- Only required for desktop -->...
```

However it does not state what file to place this code in.  Does it belong in **index.html** or in **app.component.html**?

And on a side note, is angular mobile ui the best platform to create a mobile web app (Not a native mobile app)?  Thank You.

Comment: Are you trying to mix angularjs (1.x) and angular (2+)?

Comment: R. Richards, thank you so much.  I downloaded the latest angular using: npm install -g @angular/cli.  I ran the ng --version command and it returns "Angular CLI: 8.3.22."

Comment: It looks like the `mobile-angular-ui` is for Angular 1.x, not Angular 8. You may want to look for some other library.

Comment: `mobile-angular-ui` is an abandoned project. Hasn't been updated in 3 years.

Comment: Take a look at: https://www.nativescript.org/nativescript-is-how-you-build-native-mobile-apps-with-angular

Comment: I see, thank you I didnt realize it was abandonded since their website did not mention that.  I will take a look at the nativescript link.  Does native script have to be installed through the google play store or can it be served as a web page to the mobile client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the question you are asking, it sounds like you might benefit from some foundational tutorials around how Angular works.

The [getting started](https://angular.io/start) & [tour of heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial) tutorials provide a lot of useful concepts around how Angular works. have you already walked through these? if not spending half a day going through those would be helpful.

Before you jump into using additional frameworks on top of Angular, you might be best served by spending a little time with those tutorials first.

To answer you question, 'what is best' is relative to what you are trying to accomplish. the various angular frameworks each provide some value to help make the development process easier. however, a solid understanding of angular fundamentals (which is what your question is hinting at) will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: Edward, thank you it is greatly appreciated.  I will read both of your links.  Basically I am trying to create a grid where I can edit/add customers.  The back-end database is sqlite.  It will be for use on the web by mobile devices.  Thank you again for taking the time to answer my question, it is greatly appreciated.